# OnSelectedIndexChanged Dropdown List without page refreshing event

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, page-refresh, scriptmanager, selectedindexchanged

I'm using the script manager + update panel on my drop down list so when the user selects something out of it, the page wouldn't refresh(this is my goal).

Here is the HTML code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:ListView ID="listProducts" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ProductID" OnItemDataBound="listProducts_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="listProducts_ItemCommand">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <div class="productoverlay">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 proizvod">
                         <div class="product">
                             <div class="glow"></div>
                             <img src='<%# "../productimg/" + Eval("FileName")%>'  alt='<%# Eval("ProductName") %>'/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-1 price">
                         <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-lg-7 pushtop">
                          <h1><%# Eval("ProductName") %></h1>

                         <p>Description: </p>
                         <p><%# Eval("ProductDescription") %></p>
                         <p>Quantity: </p><asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageQuantity" TextMode="Number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                        
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="DropDownList1" eventname="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                        <ContentTemplate>
                           <asp:DropDownList  ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> 
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add to cart"  CommandName="AddToCart" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID")%>'/>
                         </div>
                 </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

And this is the code for the OnSelectedIndexChanged event:

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ddl = sender as DropDownList;
            var val = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
            rlsp_PrCategories_ByID_Result pr = ServiceClass.ProductCatByID(val);
            Label lblPrice = ddl.Parent.FindControl("lblPrice") as Label;
            if(pr!=null)
            lblPrice.Text = "$ " + pr.Price;
        }
```

The problem is that now when I added script manager + update panel (async postback trigger), now when I select something out of the dropdown list, the page doesn't refreshes, but the label also doesn't shows anything (it should change price when I select something out of the drop down menu).

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me out?

P.S. I just checked if the event fires up now when user selects something, and yes it fires up, but I don't seem to be able to see the content of that label (its not printed out on the page)...?

Comment: Nevermind... I figured it out... I had to put the label in the update panel also...

Comment: I dont use Updatepanels, but have u tried adding: 
UpdatePanel1.Update()
at the end of the selectedIndexChanged handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell the updatepanel to refresh after doing edits, because updatemode is set to conditional in ur markup.

```
 UpdatePanel1.Update()
```